# VB.Net OpenXML Conditional Page Break

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am using the OpenXML library to auto generate Word files.  I have a function that takes a group of files and merges them into one document. As I merge a new file into a document, I want each file to start on a new page.  But, I don't want to have any blank pages. The code  I have mostly works, but an issue comes up is if a file being merged in is a filled page, then a page break is still added, resulting in an empty page being added.  I am not sure how to best deal with this, to prevent blank pages from being added.  Here is my code:

```
Public Sub MergeFiles(ByVal filePaths As List(Of String), ByVal fileName As String)
        Dim newFile As String = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath & "PDF_Templates\TempFolder\catalog-" & Guid.NewGuid.ToString & ".docx"
        File.Copy(fileName, newFile)
        Dim counter As Integer = 0

        For Each filePath As String In filePaths
            Dim wordDoc As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(newFile, True)
            Using wordDoc
                Dim mainPart As MainDocumentPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart
                Dim altChunkId As String = "altChunkId" & counter
                Dim chunk As AlternativeFormatImportPart = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId)
                Dim fileStream As FileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open)

                Using fileStream
                    chunk.FeedData(fileStream)
                End Using

                Dim AltChunk As AltChunk = New AltChunk()
                AltChunk.Id = altChunkId
                ' Dont add a page break to the first page.
                If counter > 0 Then
                    Dim last As OpenXmlElement = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements().LastOrDefault(Function(e) TypeOf e Is Paragraph OrElse TypeOf e Is AltChunk)
                    last.InsertAfterSelf(New Paragraph(New Run(New Break() With {
                                    .Type = BreakValues.Page
                                    })))
                End If

                mainPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(Of AltChunk)(AltChunk, mainPart.Document.Body.Elements(Of Paragraph).Last())
                mainPart.Document.Save()
                wordDoc.Close()
            End Using
            counter = counter + 1
        Next


    End Sub
```

Comment: This is tricky, since there's no information about the structure of these documents... However, using hard-coded page breaks is generally no ideal. Word has two formatting features that force page breaks: Next Page section breaks and the paragraph-level formatting "Page Break Before". Based on what we (don't) know, my inclination is to suggest the latter. Combine just two documents then open the result in Word. Find where the second document begins and click there. Go to Home tab, Paragraph group and click the dialog box launcher to get the Format Paragraph dialog box...

Comment: ...Go to the "Line and Page breaks" tab and activate "Page Break Before". Observe the behavior in the document. If it's what you need, save to a new file name. Open the original in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool, then use the Compare feature to bring in the modified document. This will provide the altered Word Open XML as well as the code to create the second from the first. That should give you the syntax to apply this formatting. You'll need to first open each document being inserted and apply this, then save - before importing the file as an altChunk.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thank you Cindy.  So, the documents that the function is combining are also system made documents.  So each out is system generated, based on a template.  I have other code that loads a Word template and finds/replaces text in book marks.  It then create over a 100 documents.  These are some of the documents being combined here.  You mentioned "Next Page"?  Is this something that my code can call?  I.e. have my script open the document and then go to the Next Page and start the insert there?

Comment: @CindyMeister and sorry for the late response, I was out of the office

Comment: ... and I didn't see these comments, for some reason... Anyway, did you TEST what I suggested in the Word UI? I can't know what will work - I don't have the files to test on.